# Paycheck Questions

Tags: salary, paycheck

I have a situation where I believe I was supposed to be paid `$1,000` more than what I actually was paid during the year. While it's not a huge amount of money it still would have been nice. I've been looking back through my paychecks to try and see if I did get the money or not but I'm having trouble telling.

I currently get paid $35,000 - but we agreed on $36,000 at the interview. I get paid in the middle of the month ( 15th or so ) once, except the first month whenever I was only paid half. Over the 11 months my paychecks have a Salaried Wages rate of `$2,916.6700` and the last paycheck I received for the year has a gross pay `YTD` of `$33,541.71`. If I assume that I only get paid half for the last half of the month, then that seems to hit the mark of `$35,000` and if I multiply the Salaried Rate * 12 I get `$35,000.04` which is right. So currently it definitely seems like **I did not get paid my $1,000** as agreed upon.

On the other-hand, if I take my `Total YTD` + `Total Withholdings` ( $33,541.71 + $6,731.94 ) = **$40273.65** - which seems flawed but I'm not 100% sure.

Now if I take what get's deposited into my bank each month ( since the January to December ) + my `Total Withholdings` I get **33,541.71**. So it seems like all of the arrows point to `$35,000` unless I'm completely missing something. Does my logic seem correct? Is there a sure-fire way to know? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

Your withholding is taken out of your pay. So if you do `YTD`+`withholding` - you count the withholding twice, that's why it doesn't add up for you.

The simple answer is to check your written contract/offer letter. See if it matches what you see, or what you expected to see. If the offer/contract states $36K - check with the payroll person at work why the discrepancy.

If you don't have any written proof of the agreed amounts (don't know if it is legal, check local laws on the requirements of documenting employment terms), then it is up to you and your employer to sort it out.

However, keep in mind: if you don't have any written proof and the employer is unwilling to adjust - one (judge?) would wonder: you've been getting paychecks monthly, which clearly state that your annual salary is $35K. Why did you wait so long to sort this out?

Comment: I honestly forgot about it since it was going to be such a small amount each month, then I needed my paychecks for my student loans and started doing the math which is when it dawned on me. Unfortunately it's a small organization ( 3 people ), so there is no payroll person, just *the boss*. Now if I do the withholding twice I get `$47005.59` which is way off, and if I  assume that I get withheld half for the last 15 days of the 12th month, I get `$36907.68` which also seems off.

Comment: @Derp withholding is *included* in the YTD amounts.

Comment: Ha, that makes sense. That's my gross income for the year so far am I right? So really to hit the `$36,000` that I'm expecting it seems like I would need a little less than a full paycheck in half a month which seems ridiculous. So it seems to me that I was not paid what was discussed unfortunately. Thanks for your help.